# Angular 2 click on specific words with spaces

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input

I have text and some words in text are with spaces like **I like R O S E S and trees.** Spaces are made with help of this function

```
this.text = this.text.replace(new RegExp(this.words.join('|'), 'g'), function insertSpaces(x) {
   return x.split('').join(' ');
 }); };
```

where text is **I like roses and trees** and word is **ROSES**, I would like to make it possible to click on the word **R O S E S** between letters and if I click there appears "-"instead of spaces. So, if I click between **R** and **O** there appears **R-O S E S** instead of **R O S E S**, if I click between **O** and **S**, appears **R O-S E S** instead of **R O S E S** and so on...is it possible with Angular2?

UPDATE

I try this code now

```
getCaretPos(oField: any, a: any) {
    if (oField.selectionStart || oField.selectionStart === '0') {
      this.caretPos = oField.selectionStart;

//assign char at choosed position to new variable
      a = this.text.charAt(this.caretPos);

//replace this char with "-"
      this.text.replace(a, '-');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This link demonstrates how to get the current caret position: http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/10/get-cursor-position-from-text-area.html#.WURW3GjythE

You could then change the text to insert the dash at that character position.

Does that sound like it would work for you?

Comment: Thank you for the hint.. does it work just with textarea? Or is it possible to work with <p> as well?

Comment: And how can I insert the dash at that character position? Sorry, I am very beginner...just tried a replace() function, but doesn't work...must be something like oField.replace('-'); ?...

Comment: Update your question with the code you are trying for the replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
getCaretPos(oField: any, a: any) {
    if (oField.selectionStart || oField.selectionStart === '0') {
      this.caretPos = oField.selectionStart;
      a = this.text.charAt(this.caretPos);
      alert(a);
      this.text = this.text.substring(0, this.caretPos) + '-' + this.text.substring(this.caretPos + 1);
    }
  }
```

Works for me, hope this will help somebody else)